# Python3 - Interpolate many arrays of varied lengths

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation

I have about 100 spectra that I need to eventually interpolate onto a single x-axis range. The data are stored as a "velocity" array of 100 sub-arrays, and a "flux" array of 100 sub-arrays. Each sub-array has a different length (in this particular case varying from about 100 to 1700), that eventually need to be interpolated onto a single velocity range, for comparison and plotting purposes. Currently, I have been trying to interpolate the arrays with respect to the shortest-length array (i.e. 100 in this case), resulting in my code looking something like this:

```
lengths=[len(VELOCITY[i]) for i in range(len(VELOCITY))]
minlen=min(lengths)
idx = np.where(np.asarray(lengths) == minlen)[0][0]
vel_new = np.linspace(VELOCITY[idx][0], VELOCITY[idx][-1],num=len(VELOCITY[idx]), endpoint=True)
for i in range(len(VELOCITY)):
    interp = interp1d(VELOCITY[i], FLUX[i], kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
    flux.append(interp(vel_new))
flux = np.asarray(flux)
```

However, the [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YjO8.png) isn't quite what I expect, with what I can only assume is extrapolated points from the interpolation becoming dominant. I'm surprised by this, considering I selected the smallest velocity array, and thus the extrapolation should be minimal.

My question is, am I going about the interpolation incorrectly? Alternatively, do you have a suggestion for a better method than the one I am pursuing? Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: If you only go over 100 values in each sub-array, you miss a lot of data, don't you?

Comment: As in, if i only interpolate over 100 values? I suppose I was worried about decreased accuracy by increasing the interpolation range and extrapolating the data, but if there's a happy middle ground somewhere I'd be interested to know, if you have a formula or something.

Comment: You have 100 functions, and you want to plot all of them, interpolated. Why do you need to treat them uniformly? Why can't you just interpolate based on all the data points of each one?